# How can I write simple Pross Pay in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, python-requests

I want ask you about **Pross Pay in python** . I had some assignments in Coursera and I solved after some times in search on google . I found solution and I solved my assignments ,but I can't understand
it. please can you explain me ? **Especially (xp)**.

enter code here`

```
#Calculate the Pay for employee
sh = input("Enter Hours")
sr = input("Enter Rate")
fh = float(sh)
fr = float(sr)
if fh >= 40 :
   print("Overtime")
   xp = (40.0 * fr +(fh -40.0)*1.5*fr)
   
else:
   print ("Regular")
   xp = (40.0 * fr +(fh -40.0)*1.5*fr)
    
print(xp)
```

Comment: Just a series of mathematical calculations based on some conditions. You should be able to understand it on ur own...

Comment: Why is the calculation exactly the same in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

The logic in your code is incorrect. If the hours are less then 40, the pay will be too low.

Try this code:

```
#Calculate the Pay for employee
sh = input("Enter Hours ")
sr = input("Enter Rate ")
fh = float(sh)
fr = float(sr)

if fh > 40 :
   print("Overtime")
   reg  = 40 * fr  # regular hours
   over = (fh - 40) * (fr * 1.5)  # overtime hours
   xp = reg + over
   
else:
   print ("Regular")
   xp = fh * fr
    
print(xp)
```

Output

```
Enter Hours 20
Enter Rate 10
Regular
200.0

Enter Hours 40
Enter Rate 10
Regular
400.0

Enter Hours 60
Enter Rate 10
Overtime
700.0
```